# How to save multiple histogram plots into multiple pdf files

Tags: python, pdf, save-as

I'm having trouble saving histogram plots from a "for loop" into multiple pdf files.

I have tried the .savefig() and the img2pdf.

```
for i,title in enumerate(titles):
    count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(dists[i], 50, normed=True, range= 
    [450,1700])
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel("g CO2-eq/day-bed " )
    plt.ylabel("Frequency")
    plt.show()

    plt.savefig[i]("nitrileglob1.pdf",bbox_inches='tight')
```

I either save one plot or none of them get saved. I want to save each of the dists[i] into a pdf file. The last line is not really working...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are saving all of your plots under the same name. You would have to change the file name in each iteration, for example

```
plt.savefig("nitrileglob" + str(i) + ".pdf",bbox_inches="tight")
```

You should also save the file before calling `plt.show()`, as this clears the current figure.